# Fixed variable in Groth16

Tags: zero-knowledge-proofs, pairings, circuit, snarks

In the paper [On the Size of Pairing-based Non-interactive Arguments](https://eprint.iacr.org/2016/260.pdf) by Jens Groth, it is always referred in the equations to satisfy that $a_0 = 1$ and the others $a_1, ..., a_m \in \mathbb{F}$.

I am not sure I understand this specification, as we can always set $a_0$ later to 1 if needed. I first thought it was to introduce the constant 1 for the arithmetic circuit basic operation but I am wondering now if this specific value has another use.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your thinking is correct!

In the [GGPR13 paper](https://eprint.iacr.org/2012/215.pdf) (see Definition 11 in section 7.1 ) quadratic arithmetic programs were introduced for proving arithmetic circuit satisfiability.  The key idea was that the satisfiability of the arithmetic circuit is equivalent to the following polynomial having zeros at certain specified values of $x$:
$$
\left( v_0(x) + \sum\limits_{k=1}^m a_k \cdot v_k(x) \right) \cdot \left( w_0(x) + \sum\limits_{k=1}^m a_k \cdot w_k(x) \right) - 
\left( y_0(x) + \sum\limits_{k=1}^m a_k \cdot y_k(x) \right)
$$

By definining $a_0=1$, it is possible to write this polynomial more compactly:
$$
\left( \sum\limits_{k=0}^m a_k \cdot v_k(x) \right) \cdot 
\left( \sum\limits_{k=0}^m a_k \cdot w_k(x) \right) - 
\left( \sum\limits_{k=0}^m a_k \cdot y_k(x) \right)
$$

This is what was done in the Groth16 paper.